# Activity Life Cycle OnStart is not calling after comes from background

Tags: android, android-activity, application-restart

In App, if i press home button app goes into background means OnResume() and OnStop() is called. After that i click the app from recent history OnRestart() and OnStart is not calling, app gets hang shows black screen. Im getting this log...

```
V/ActivityThread: updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{2b08d4ef token=android.os.BinderProxy@11356f46 {in.passionconnect.application/in.passionconnect.application.HomeActivity}} show : false
```

My code [here](http://pastebin.com/9mYS7ZY3) Please tell what im doing wrong. Thanks in advance...

Comment: check out [Activity life Cycle](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html), according to it once activity is paused, it will call `Resume` method.

Comment: yes OnResume is calling for me... and OnStop also calling....

Comment: call methods at onResume as it is suggested in developer guide.

Comment: how i cant understand please help me